# wordpress/php redirect stops working

Tags: php, wordpress, header

struggling with this issue for a while now.
On a ecommerce plugin, after a user makes a purchase the analytics code is inserted and then the user gets redirected.
problem is the checkout gets stucked on a white page and all i can see in the page source is the analytics code.
I assume after that the redirect happens but it throws a headers already sent error.
This is the view source of the page:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    var _gaq = _gaq || [];

    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);

    _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'domain.com']);

    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

        _gaq.push(['_addTrans',
        '61',                                     // order ID - required
        'outdoor-om™', // affiliation or store name
        '9.95',   // total - required
        '0.00',              // tax
        '0.00',         // shipping
        'St Petersburg',                  // city
        'Missouri',                 // state or province
        'US'                // country
    ]);

_gaq.push(['_addItem','61','','XYT','Fresh','9.95','1']);

_gaq.push(['_trackTrans']);

(function() {

        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;

        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';

        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);

      })();

    </script>
```

Comment: Is this only partial source for this page?  I ask, because if this is the entire source, there is nothing there which would indicate to the browser that this is to be interpreted as javascript (i.e. javascript tags).

Comment: sorry for that, i fixed original code, didnt noticed the script tags are not aded

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing on that page that would seem to attempt to do a redirect. You should get a white page (since there is no HTML output).

If you want to redirect using PHP `header()` function you can't send any output to the client.

You probably should be putting you google analytics code either on the previous page or the nextopage and not have this intermittent page.

Alternatively, you could put a javascript redirect in place on this page, however to me the whole workflow here seems kind of odd.  Typcailyl one would simply place a transaction recordation call to Google analytics on their checkout success page.